# Launch adb commands in python

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, adb

I try launch adb commands in python without custom modules.

try:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe',   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
process.stdin.write("adb shell uninstall com.q.q".encode("utf8"))
process.stdin.write("adb shell install C:\\...\\qwerty.apk".encode("utf8"))
```

but this not working. Code finish without results

Answer (score 2):

cannot test with your exact commands but that works fine:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
o,e = process.communicate(b"dir\n")
print(o)
```

(I get the contents of my directory)

so for your example, you're missing the line terminators when sending commands. The commands aren't issued to the `cmd` program, the pipe is broken before that.

That would work better:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe',   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
process.stdin.write(b"adb shell uninstall com.q.q\n")
process.stdin.write(b"adb shell install C:\\...\\qwerty.apk\n")
o,e = process.communicate()
```

but this is a very strange way to run commands. Just use `check_call`, with args split properly:

```
subprocess.check_call(["adb","shell","uninstall","com.q.q"])
subprocess.check_call(["adb","shell","install",r"C:\...\qwerty.apk"])
```

Comment: thank you very much! I found mistake. "shell" superfluous